# Retrieve multiple lookup values in large dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['138249','Cat']
,['103669','Cat']
,['191826','Cat']
,['196655','Cat']
,['103669','Cat']
,['116780','Dog']
,['184831','Dog']
,['196655','Dog']
,['114333','Dog']
,['123757','Dog']]


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Hash','Name'])

print(df1)

data2 = [
'138249',
'103669',
'191826',
'196655',
'116780',
'184831',
'114333',
'123757',]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['Hash'])
```

I want to write a code that will take the item in the second dataframe, scan the leftmost values in the first dataframe, then return all matching values from the first dataframe into a single cell in the second dataframe.

Here's the result I am aiming for:

[image]

Here's what I have tried:

```
#attempt one: use groupby to squish up the dataset.  No results

past = df1.groupby('Hash')

print(past)

#attempt two: use merge.  Result: empty dataframe

past1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, right_index=True, left_on='Hash')

print(past1)

#attempt three: use pivot.  Result: not the right format.  

past2 = df1.pivot(index = None, columns = 'Hash', values = 'Name')

print(past2)
```

I can do this in Excel with the VBA code [here](https://www.get-digital-help.com/2010/12/20/excel-udf-lookup-and-return-multiple-values-concatenated-into-one-cell/)  but this code crashes when I apply to my real dataset (likely because it is too big - approximately  30,000 rows long)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC first `agg` and `join` with `df1` then `reindex` using `df2`

```
df1.groupby('Hash')['Name'].agg(','.join).reindex(df2.Hash).reset_index()
     Hash     Name
0  138249      Cat
1  103669  Cat,Cat
2  191826      Cat
3  196655  Cat,Dog
4  116780      Dog
5  184831      Dog
6  114333      Dog
7  123757      Dog
```

Comment: It works!  thank you.  I just have to wait 10 mins to accept your answer